# Capture Class Text - Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to capture an element of a web page using selenium in python

```
<span class="_2-1_O"><span dir="auto" class="_1jlxc _3Whw5">Ana Smith</span></span>
```

I'm trying to capture the name Ana Smith in Phyton:

```
nome_contato =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1jlxc _3Whw5").text
```

However, python cannot locate

```py
    try:
        name=  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1jlxc _3Whw5").text

    except Exception as e:
        print("|False")
```

Result: |False

Comment: Is it raising an exception or just returning an empty string?

Comment: raising an exception - Edit code - Print False

Comment: In that case provide the Traceback of your program, it helps locating the error/bug

Answer (score 1):

.text does not need () it's just ".text"

In general it's easier to help with more information, but from the information you gave that's the main issue that I see.

Comment: Edited or excerpt, but do not find.
I want to access only the name Ana Smith, but the element cannot be found in the code

Comment: So that could either be because the page isn't loading quickly enough, so you'd have to use the wait function in selenium but also, find_elements method returns a list, and .text does not work on a list. To get around this you have to either iterate through the list using a for loop and use .text on each iteration or if you really only are looking at one tag you can just make it find_element rather than elements.

Answer (score 0):

`find_elements_by_class_name` returns a list, be careful. You can use `find_element_by_class_name` if you want the first element or you can select one element of the list returned by `find_elements_by_class_name`.

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and wait for element to be visisble 
`visibility_of_element_located()` and following `css selector`

**Code**:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"._1jlxc._3Whw5"))).text)
```

you need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider a couple of things:

- `find_elements_by_*` will return a list. But you want that particular element. So you have to use `find_element_by_*` instead.
- `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` takes a single class. So it won't accept multiple classes as in:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_class_name("_1jlxc _3Whw5")
  ```
- Most important, the element is a dynamic element, so to print the text **Ana Smith** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath"))).text)
    ```
- However, the value(s) ofthe *class* attribute, `_1jlxc`, `_3Whw5`, etc indicates that the values are generated by either [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), etc. So those values are never static and they would keep on changing everytime you access the webpage.

---

### Solution

Apart from inducing *WebDriverWait* you have to construct either [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) or [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based on static attributes possibly from some ancestor elements.